# why does the shell try to overwrite a file with a different name?

Tags: macos, zsh

This is on MacOS and I am using ZSH. The folder icon file is 'icon?'

I have the following files:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 thomas  staff     0 May 17 17:36 Icon?
drwxr-xr-x   9 thomas  staff   288 Oct 21 01:55 Icons
```

and I wanted to rename 'Icons' to 'icons'

> mv Icons icons

but I get the following message:

> overwrite icons? (y/n [n])

why is that?

Comment: I think this has to do with case sensitivity since it complains about the same file name, not another. The ? is most likely part of the question and not the filename.

Comment: ahhh, yes, you're probably right; I assumed the '?' was part of the file name and I didn't get it! sometimes you really need someone else to look at something to really see it :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : You likely suspect correctly, but why is Zsh doing this warning? We can control glob-patterns to work case-insensitive, but this does not apply here. Also, Zsh has it's own `mv` command, but the man page does not say that it would warn in this case. I think it's odd. @Thomas : Do you also get the error if you execute either `command mv Icons icons` or `command mv -f Icons icons`?

Comment: @user1934428, with 'command', the warning doesn't appear.

Comment: So this is a "feature" of the builtin-version of `mv`, similar to the builtin `rm`, which also asks back under certain conditions.